# Memory Exhausting in mysql_free_result()

Tags: php, out-of-memory

I made a method on my class to fetch and store in a array all the results the desired SQL statement has in it, and it works just fine. Now, after some months in production, I came across this error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 3503272 bytes) in C:\xxpathxx\class.DGC_Gerais.php on line 0
```

As I begin to inspect, I tracked the error to the `mysql_free_result()`, but upon commenting that line, it still doenst work.

Here's the `_fetch` method:

```
PUBLIC static function _fetch($sql){
        $q = mysql_query($sql);

        if(mysql_num_rows($q) > 0):

            for($a=0 ; $linha = mysql_fetch_row($q) ; $a++){ // forEach row.
                foreach($linha as $chave => $valor): // forEach field.
                    $result[$a][$chave] = $valor;
                endforeach;

            }

//          mysql_free_result($q);

            return $result;

        else:
            return false;
        endif;

    }
```

Comment: You might consider using pagination if your dataset is too much for your memory to handle.

Answer (score 1):

1. That code is extremely convoluted and can be simplified to:

   ```
   public static function _fetch($sql) {
       $q = mysql_query($sql);

       if (mysql_num_rows($q) == 0) {
           return false;
       }

       $result = array();
       while ($linha = mysql_fetch_row($q)) {
           $result[] = $linha;
       }
       return $result;
   }
   ```

   Does exactly the same without double loops.
2. The problem is that you're fetching all that data from the database and are storing it in `$result`, which means it needs to be stored in memory. And PHP limits the amount of memory available to scripts by default, so you're simply exceeding that limit. `mysql_free_result` has nothing as such to do with it. First try to fetch less data, or to process the data inside that `while` loop without needing to store everything in an array.

   If that doesn't help, carefully turn up the memory limit with `ini_set('memory_limit', $limit)`.

Comment: What do you mean by saying convoluted? Too 'dirty'?

Comment: 1) Fail early, don't have long nested `if..else` with `return false` at the end. 2) If there are no result rows, `$result` is never defined and `return $result` triggers an error. Well, in your case you have `return false` instead, but it's a typical error to not initialise the array. 3) Looping to assign every key and value of an array to another array is nonsense, just assign the array as is. 4) Manually keeping track of numeric indices with `$a` is superfluous, that's what `$result[] =` is for.

Comment: Your answer helped, but I don't think thats it, because in this particular case, it processed 450 rows, and then it exhausted, but I've already processed 2000+ rows from the same table, without any issues or warnings..

Comment: Well, your script exhausts memory at 64MB, which is quite a lot of data for a little PHP script. I don't know how much data you're processing there obviously, you need to figure that out. Seems like the most likely explanation from what I'm seeing though.

Comment: I'll try to figure it out then! Thank you again